# How could I run a websockets server alongside another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I want to run a [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) server alongside another function in my program, however when I try to use `asyncio.gather()` the other function runs fine while the websockets server closes instantly, I think because I cannot use `loop.run_forever()`. My code is as follows:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

from server import server, game_controller

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = asyncio.gather(
    websockets.serve(server, 'localhost', 5000),
    game_controller()
)

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Putting `loop.run_forever()` there when using `run_until_complete(...server...)` works fine, but it doesn't work with `gather`. I'm fairly new to asyncio, so I'm not sure how I could go about fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I forgot to make the `game_controller()` function `async`.